# How to tail and use grep for all the log files inside a folder and subfolders using subprocess?

Tags: python, flask, grep, subprocess, tail

I am using flask and I am trying to tail and get the lines containing Error and or Warning in all the log files inside the folder and subfolders using subprocess. I show the outcome on the webapp using Jinja in my html file in a div. If I use "**/*.log" to select all log files in the folder and subfolders the div is empty and I do not see any lines. If I use the exact path of a logfile it does show the correct lines of the certain log. Am I doing something wrong?

```
@ app.route("/")
def index():
    # get stream name in card
    naam = os.path.basename('../TESTCLIENT.log')
    naamUitkomst = os.path.splitext(naam)[0]
  
    #gets log lines containing Error and or Warning
    out = subprocess.run(['tail', '-n', '10', '|', 'egrep', '-w', 'Error|Warning', "**/*.log"], capture_output=True)

    return render_template('index.html', value=naamUitkomst, result=out.stdout.decode())
```

```
<div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <button id="btnColor" class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                            {{ value }}
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-               parent="#accordionExample">
                    <div id="test" class="card-body>
                         {{ result }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I tried using the direct path to a single logfile in the command. If I do so it does work for the single file but the moment I use **/*.log to select all the logfiles the webapp shows nothing. I have tried different python modules to excecute Unix commands in python but subprocess is the only one that sort of works for me.

Comment: you probably need shell=True and write your command as a string. But you'd be better off rewriting the whole tail/grep/... in native python. Use `glob.glob` to match patterns. Else your code depends on external command and is less portable

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because without `shell=True`, the `run` command passes the `**/*.log` argument literally without expanding the arguments.

But better drop all the underlying commands, pipes and processes. Why not just code it in python? My attempt (not tested)

```
import glob,re

# list of matching lines
out = []
# match your pattern
for logfile in glob.glob("**/*.log",recursive=True):
    # read the last 10 lines of each logfile
    with open(logfile) as f:
        for line in f.readlines()[-10:]:
        # extract errors using regex and "word only" mode
        m = re.search(r"\b(Error|Warning)\b",line)
        if m:
            out.append(line)

# full result as text buffer
out = "".join(out)
```

Comment: I found out about the tail command after experience some performance issues because some of the files are pretty big. Will I have any performance issues using this you think?

Comment: this version reads all the lines so it may be slow. I don't know if tail has a trick to seek to the end of the file then figure out the 10 last lines.